# Waiting values to be set in iteration through list javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an Access Control List, but when I set a `function` to its properties it doesn't work correctly, because the current iteration read `function` as a `null` value, but when I set it to `func.toString()` works.

[Here's my running code.](https://codesandbox.io/s/jz972304w9)

line85: try to change the `perm.when = func;` to `perm.when = func.toString();` it'll add correct. but i need it as a function.

if you write

```
console.log([func]); //[f]
perm.when = [func]; // [null]
```

Can I read it as a function instead of `null`?

Comment: Are you doing some sort of serialization?

Comment: Are these js files loaded separately or do you bundle them?

Comment: This codesandbox uses `parcel`. @JonasWilms @avdg

Comment: Using `JSON.stringify()` on an Object with methods won't serialize the methods.

Comment: I tried it but doesn't work @RandyCasburn

Comment: It's way better to keep code and data separated, you can use data to refer to a strategy like "allowAnyUser" "onlyMe" to add score (or something)

Comment: You misunderstood my point. The code on line 91 of `acl.js` (`localStorage.setItem("acl", JSON.stringify(intialStorage));`) won't store `func` as part of `intialStorage`.

Comment: Thanks, I Solved it using `eval()`. @RandyCasburn